# Getting err_empty_response when I try to submit a form

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm not sure what the issue is, I put: `echo 'test';` at the beginning of my code and that wasn't shown either, only ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, what could be causing this?

Php Code:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

//$email_to = "user@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "New customer requesting information/appointment";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}





    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";






require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");


$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password = "pass";

$mail->From     = "user@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("sendto@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject  = $email_subject;
$mail->Body     = $email_message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}

?>




Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

the echo 'test'; does not do anything.

Comment: We need to see some code in order to help you, manythings may cause this. What happens if you to die("test");? I bet it'll show

Comment: Check if php/apache service is UP. Are you using WAMP, XAMPP, Apache? Which OS Windows or Linux?

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, I added in the code and put in a die('test'), and it showed 'test', what does this mean?

Comment: If it's showing that 'test' but not getting any further, I'd guess your `require` on the PHPailer autoloader is failing. Check your web server error log.

Answer (score 0):

Write Down **exit();** function after echo statement.

Comment: Thank you for responding, after playing around with the exit(); function what seems to be my problem is the if(!$mail->Send()), however since it's not sending I'm curious as to why it isn't printing out any errors.